# Problem running c code on ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I have downloaded a zip file of C programs the website
https://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~wally.gilks/adaptive.rejection/web_page/Welcome.html

I have extracted the zip file and tried to run the c program `arms_main01.c` in Ubuntu terminal, but the program is throwing error in linking other files.  How can I run this file from Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: Have you compiled it? This is too vague. Please [edit] your question and include the exact commands and error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Directory Contains:**

```
arms01a.m  arms02.m  arms.doc  arms_main01a.c  arms_main02.c  arms.nouniform.c  arms01.m   arms.c    arms.h    arms_main01.c   arms.method
```

**Compile Using gcc**
Open terminal inside the directory and type:

```
gcc -c arms_main01.c -o arms_main01.o
gcc -c arms.c -o arms.o
gcc -o arms01 arms_main01.o arms.o -lm -lc
```

**Running The Program** 
Executable file created called: `arms01` , run it as:

```
./arms01
```

**Output Result**
This program created an output file called: `arms.out01`, to see the content:

```
cat arms.out01
```

Done.

---

By the way, the directory contains 3 main programs:

```
arms_main01.c, arms_main01a.c, arms_main02.c
```

*In the example above, we compile and run: `arms_main01.c`*

Please see:

```
arms01.m, arms01a.m, arms02.m
```

To know how to compile and run the programs according to the example above.